# Does similar Titles considered duplicates relating to SEO

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have built a testing service and I wonder if I should be concerned that search engines will consider similar titles as duplicates.

For example:

1. Some URLs title can be differed from others by only one word such as "Senior" and "Junior"

   - Title A: C++ Online Test for Juniors
   - Title B: C++ Online Test for Seniors
2. Another example is with the "+" sign:

   - Title A: C Standard Library Online Test for Seniors
   - Title B: C++ Standard Library Online Test for Seniors

Should I assume search engines will understand there is a difference in the titles? And the titles are not duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search engines considers titles as duplicate only when titles are identical. It's normal because title must be specific for one page and it's not logical that two pages presents the same thing.

Thus, if you have a little difference in your titles, there is no problem for duplicate title issues. You can present C++ for juniors differently than you present C++ for seniors.